# How to debug Angular 4 application?

Tags: angular

The project has a lot of npm dependencies. It is compiled succesfull, but the browser freezes when I try to open URL localhost:3000.

I see just title of page and blnk body. It try to load page. But it is loaded unlimited time.

I dont know the reason, how to debug application in this case?

Comment: Open the developer tools on your browser (F12)

Comment: You can start by reading [Everything you need to know about debugging Angular applications](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-debugging-angular-applications-d308ed8a51b4)

Comment: I cannot open tools, because browser is frozen

Comment: @Daniel open devtools first and then open the localhost.

Comment: clear your browser's cheche and try in chrome's incognito window to debug your application.